# How to know when printer's print method completes printing a file?

Tags: java, printing

I'm developing a JAVA program that prints a file.
I need to know when the printer has completed printing the file, I've found this simple code that it is interesting:

```
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.DocAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintServiceAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterStateReason;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterStateReasons;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Severity;
import javax.print.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * PrintTest
 */
public class PrintTest implements PrintServiceAttributeListener,PrintJobListener,Doc, Printable, PrintJobAttributeListener {

  private static final transient String TEXT = "12345";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintTest test = new PrintTest();
    test.checkPrinters();
  }

  public void checkPrinters() {
    Thread newThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
    PrintService ps = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().getPrintService();

    DocFlavor[] myFlavors = ps.getSupportedDocFlavors();
    ps.addPrintServiceAttributeListener(PrintTest.this);
    DocPrintJob docJob = ps.createPrintJob();
      docJob.addPrintJobAttributeListener(PrintTest.this, null);
    docJob.addPrintJobListener(PrintTest.this);
    try {
      docJob.print(PrintTest.this,null);
    }
    catch (PrintException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    } });

    newThread.start();
    /**
    PrintServiceAttributeSet attSet = ps.getAttributes();
    PrinterStateReasons psr = ps.getAttribute(PrinterStateReasons.class);

    if (psr != null) {
      Set<PrinterStateReason> errors = psr.printerStateReasonSet(Severity.REPORT);
      for (PrinterStateReason reason : errors)
        System.out.printf(" Reason : %s",reason.getName());
      System.out.println();
    }          */
  }

  public void attributeUpdate(PrintServiceAttributeEvent psae) {
    System.out.println(psae.getAttributes());
  }

  public void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Transfer completed");
  }

  public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Completed");
  }

  public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Failed");
    PrinterStateReasons psr = pje.getPrintJob().getPrintService().getAttribute(PrinterStateReasons.class);
    if (psr != null) {
      Set<PrinterStateReason> errors = psr.printerStateReasonSet(Severity.REPORT);
      for (PrinterStateReason reason : errors)
        System.out.printf(" Reason : %s",reason.getName());
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Canceled");
  }

  public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("No more events");
  }

  public void printJobRequiresAttention(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Job requires attention");
    PrinterStateReasons psr = pje.getPrintJob().getPrintService().getAttribute(PrinterStateReasons.class);
    if (psr != null) {
      Set<PrinterStateReason> errors = psr.printerStateReasonSet(Severity.REPORT);
      for (PrinterStateReason reason : errors)
        System.out.printf(" Reason : %s",reason.getName());
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public DocFlavor getDocFlavor() {
    return DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public Object getPrintData() throws IOException {
    return this;
  }

  public DocAttributeSet getAttributes() {
    return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public Reader getReaderForText() throws IOException {
    return null; //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public InputStream getStreamForBytes() throws IOException {
    return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
    return pageIndex == 0 ? PAGE_EXISTS : NO_SUCH_PAGE;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public void attributeUpdate(PrintJobAttributeEvent pjae) {
    System.out.println("Look out");
  }
}
```

So, the method that interest me is this:

```
public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Completed");
  }
```

but it doesn't works for me. The issue is that the printer doesn't support this type of code. Can someone tell me a model of printer that support this code?

Comment: What does the error message say?  Did you check the console? (I am assuming it is a run-time error instead of compiling error)

Comment: For mself, I don't recall ever seeing an application (other than the OS print queue manager) ever notify me when my print job was complete. So my guess is that this is rarely, perhaps never implemented

Comment: `printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje)`  Called to notify the client that no more events will be delivered. One cause of this event being generated is if the job has successfully completed, but the printing system is limited in capability and cannot verify this. This event is required to be delivered if none of the other terminal events (completed/failed/canceled) are delivered. I think if we get printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje)  invoked we can assume our priting was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sample code [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/print/determine-that-print-job-has-finished/):

It looks like you need to implement your `PrintJobAdapter`. The relevant bits are:

```
package com.your.package;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;

public class DetermineThatPrintJobHasFinished {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       //...    see example in link

      // Locate the default print service for this environment.    
      PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

      // Create and return a PrintJob capable of handling data from    
      // any of the supported document flavors.    
      DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();

      // register a listener to get notified when the job is complete    
      JobCompleteMonitor monitor = new JobCompleteMonitor();    
      printJob.addPrintJobListener(monitor);

      // Construct a SimpleDoc with the specified print data, doc flavor and doc attribute set.    
      Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

      // Print a document with the specified job attributes.    
      printJob.print(doc, null);    
      monitor.waitForJobCompletion();

      is.close();
    }

    private static class JobCompleteMonitor extends PrintJobAdapter {   
        private boolean completed = false;

        @Override
        public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        private void signalCompletion() {
           synchronized (JobCompleteMonitor.this) { 
               completed = true;    
               JobCompleteMonitor.this.notify();    
           }
        }

        public synchronized void waitForJobCompletion() {    
            try {
                while (!completed) {
                    wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but the problem isn't solved. when i run the program, it sends the file to the printer, then it terminates. I need that the program wait until the printer terminates to print the file, then the program has to call the method PrintJobComplete

Answer (score 0):

it's not the best efficient but you could wait until the Attribute: 'queued-job-count' is equal to Zero :

```
public final static void waitEndJobs(final PrintService printService) throws InterruptedException {

    int queue = 1;
    while (queue != 0) {
        final AttributeSet attributes = printService.getAttributes();
        final Attribute a = Arrays.stream(attributes.toArray())//
                .filter(o -> o.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("queued-job-count"))//
                .findFirst()//
                .orElse(null);
        queue = Integer.parseInt(attributes.get(a.getClass()).toString());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my point Rx or Project Reactor can very help with this old java printer api. I also have faced this problem recently, and currently I have finished on next version. maybe it will help to somebody

first, if you are using pdfbox as me, then

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PrinterDeviceServiceImpl implements PrinterDeviceService {

    @Override
    public StreamEx<PrintService> getAvailablePrinters() {
        return of(PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPrinterExists(String printerName) {
        return getAvailablePrinters()
                .anyMatch(p -> p.getName().equals(printerName));
    }

    @Override
    public PrintService getPrinter(String printerName) {
        return getAvailablePrinters()
                .findFirst(p -> p.getName().equals(printerName))
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<PrintTaskStatus> print(String printerName, InputStream source) {
        try {
            PrintService printer = getPrinter(printerName);
            if (printer == null) {
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("printer is null"));
            }

            PDDocument document = Unchecked.supplier(() -> PDDocument.load(source));

            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

            job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document, Orientation.PORTRAIT));
            job.setPrintService(printer);

            Paper paper = new Paper();
            paper.setSize(500, 500); //TODO: lets get it from configs or task request
            paper.setImageableArea(0.0, 0.0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight()); // no margins

            // custom page format
            PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
            pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

            Book book = new Book();

            book.append(new PDFPrintable(document), pageFormat, document.getNumberOfPages());
            job.setPageable(book);

            HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            attr.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
            attr.add(PrintQuality.HIGH);
            job.print(attr);

            return Mono.create(sink -> {
                /*If exec thread is UI or from http pool, then maybe better idea is to attach it to another independent one or run print in another one!*/
                while (!isPrintCompleted(printer)) {
                    log.debug("I'm waiting to printer processed queue");
                    Unchecked.runnable(() -> Thread.sleep(1000));
                }
                /*you can wait some fixed or dynamic time based on how big your document etc and finish with error state if it needed*/
                log.debug("printer queue have processed :)");
                sink.success(PrintTaskStatus.Completed);
            });
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ExceptionHelpers.logError(ex, log);
            return Mono.just(PrintTaskStatus.Failed);
        }
    }

    private boolean isPrintCompleted(PrintService printer) {
        return Arrays.stream(printer.getAttributes().toArray())
                .filter(att -> att instanceof QueuedJobCount)
                .map(QueuedJobCount.class::cast)
                .findFirst()
                .map(queuedJobCount -> queuedJobCount.getValue() == 0)
                .orElse(false);
    }
}
```

second, if you are preferred only default printer api then replace print method to:

```
    @Override
    public Mono<PrintTaskStatus> print(String printerName, InputStream source) {
        PrintService printer = getPrinter(printerName);
        if (printer == null) {
            return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("printer is null"));
        }

        try {
            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
            DocPrintJob printJob = printer.createPrintJob();

            CustomPrintJobListener monitor = new CustomPrintJobListener();
            printJob.addPrintJobListener(monitor);

            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(source, flavor, null);

            PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            pras.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
            pras.add(PrintQuality.NORMAL);
            pras.add(new Copies(1));
            printJob.print(doc, pras);

            return monitor.getJobMono();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ExceptionHelpers.logError(ex, log);
            return Mono.just(PrintTaskStatus.Failed);
        }
    }

    @Slf4j
    private static class CustomPrintJobListener extends PrintJobAdapter {
        private final EmitterProcessor<PrintTaskStatus> emitter = EmitterProcessor.create();

        @Override
        public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            emitter.onNext(PrintTaskStatus.Canceled);
            log.info("Print job canceled :| ");
        }

        @Override
        public void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            log.info("Print data transfer completed ;) ");
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            emitter.onNext(PrintTaskStatus.Completed);
            log.info("Print job completed :) ");
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            emitter.onNext(PrintTaskStatus.Failed);
            log.info("Print job failed :( ");
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            emitter.onNext(PrintTaskStatus.Completed);
            log.info("No more events to the job :|");
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobRequiresAttention(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            log.info("Print job requires attention :O ");
        }

        public Mono<PrintTaskStatus> getJobMono() {
            return emitter.next();
        }
    }
```

Good luck :)